# Power BI :: how to draw a curve in a scattered chart?

Tags: plot, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a graphic that we have created in Azure Log Analytics.

Such graphic is meant to show how a database is used based on 100 plot dots:

[image]

If I download those 100 points in a CSV they look like this:

| percentageDTU | ResourceId | percentageTimeSpendAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | HelloResource | 100.0697837 |
| 1 | HelloResource | 58.40893231 |
| 2 | HelloResource | 51.01186322 |
| 3 | HelloResource | 48.29030007 |
| 4 | HelloResource | 47.034194 |
| 5 | HelloResource | 45.77808793 |
| 6 | HelloResource | 42.9867411 |
| 7 | HelloResource | 32.65875785 |
| 8 | HelloResource | 29.23935799 |
| 9 | HelloResource | 27.70411724 |
| 10 | HelloResource | 25.47103978 |
| 11 | HelloResource | 23.65666434 |
| 12 | HelloResource | 22.3307746 |
| 13 | HelloResource | 21.35380321 |
| 14 | HelloResource | 20.93510119 |
| 15 | HelloResource | 19.9581298 |
| 16 | HelloResource | 18.63224006 |
| 17 | HelloResource | 18.2833217 |
| 18 | HelloResource | 16.74808095 |
| 19 | HelloResource | 15.77110956 |
| 20 | HelloResource | 14.86392184 |
| 21 | HelloResource | 14.02651779 |
| 22 | HelloResource | 13.25889742 |
| 23 | HelloResource | 12.3517097 |
| 24 | HelloResource | 12.21214236 |
| 25 | HelloResource | 11.51430565 |
| 26 | HelloResource | 11.1653873 |
| 27 | HelloResource | 10.88625262 |
| 28 | HelloResource | 9.839497558 |
| 29 | HelloResource | 9.281228193 |
| 30 | HelloResource | 9.141660851 |
| 31 | HelloResource | 9.00209351 |
| 33 | HelloResource | 8.932309839 |
| 34 | HelloResource | 8.862526169 |
| 36 | HelloResource | 8.513607816 |
| 38 | HelloResource | 8.443824145 |
| 39 | HelloResource | 8.234473133 |
| 40 | HelloResource | 8.094905792 |
| 41 | HelloResource | 7.81577111 |
| 42 | HelloResource | 7.606420098 |
| 43 | HelloResource | 7.536636427 |
| 44 | HelloResource | 7.327285415 |
| 45 | HelloResource | 7.048150733 |
| 46 | HelloResource | 6.908583391 |
| 48 | HelloResource | 6.559665038 |
| 50 | HelloResource | 6.420097697 |
| 52 | HelloResource | 6.350314027 |
| 53 | HelloResource | 3.489183531 |
| 54 | HelloResource | 3.140265178 |
| 55 | HelloResource | 3.070481507 |
| 56 | HelloResource | 3.000697837 |
| 58 | HelloResource | 2.861130495 |
| 59 | HelloResource | 2.791346825 |
| 67 | HelloResource | 2.651779484 |
| 71 | HelloResource | 2.512212142 |
| 76 | HelloResource | 2.442428472 |
| 78 | HelloResource | 2.372644801 |
| 79 | HelloResource | 2.30286113 |
| 93 | HelloResource | 2.23307746 |
| 95 | HelloResource | 2.163293789 |
| 96 | HelloResource | 2.093510119 |
| 97 | HelloResource | 2.023726448 |
| 98 | HelloResource | 1.953942777 |
| 99 | HelloResource | 1.605024424 |
| 100 | HelloResource | 1.325889742 |

but when I import them in Power BI and I select the scatter chart, as result, I only have 1 dot:

[image]

How can I draw a line instead?

You can also propose new visual to downloads, I will be happy to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?
[image]

Try a line chart instead.

[image]